# Rails, Security risk of adding secrets.yml to Git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I've just started learning Ruby On Rails and have come across a course where the instructor emphasises that not adding /config/secrets.yml to .gitignore is a security risk when using GitHub (public repo).

But when working through the established book ["Agile Rails 5"](https://pragprog.com/book/rails5/agile-web-development-with-rails-5) by Pragmatic Programmers they don't mention this at all, even when demonstrating adding the project to Git.

So my question is:

Does including this secrets.yml file expose some kind of security risk, if so how/why/what?

Comment: My new self now looks back at this rather foolish, self explanatory question and indeed, that is a palm in my face... Wow, really? But yeah. Wish it could vanish like morning dew in hot sunlight.

Answer (score 3):

> Does including this secrets.yml file expose some kind of security
>   risk, if so how/why/what?

`secrets.yml`, as the name itself says, is a file where you *store all the important keys and credentials of various services/APIs*. If your repo is **public**, then exposing `secrets.yml` would be a potential risk which could lead to potential theft/damage of your important information. In that case it obvious to add that file to `.gitignore` to not to show up in the code repo.

Even if the repo is **private** you should consider adding it to `.gitinore`. A secret is a secret after all!

Comment: Hmm... Strange that it isn't mentioned in the book I linked to. Is it considered common knowledge in the Rails community to do this?

Comment: @cseder Yes! Not that the files that contain secret information. Any files that to be ignored can be added to `.gitignore`.

Comment: @cseder - the concept of "secrets" isn't Rails specific. On any platform we code we use different ways to prevent leakage of cryptographic or other sensitive information. I'm not sure how detailed the book should be about this issue, but I think it's okay that it makes the the assumption that you would know to keep your information safe when you work on actual projects. For example, would you add a private TLS/SSL certificate to your public repo? - even without being told, I hope you know this would be a very bad thing.

Comment: Yes, I see. I was pretty sure that this file was storing some sensitive information as it is named "secrets.yml" but I haven't yet read enough about Rails to know if it was something to care about. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: @Pavan : Hi there! Sorry for messing with this old thing, and for unchecking your answer as the solution to my "problem", I'm trying to delete this foolish question, I don't understand why I asked such an obvious question to begin with, so, being the only question I've asked on SO doesn't do me any good :) Was hoping maybe you could delete your answer, so I can delete my outdated and mostly irrelevant / self-explanatory question.

Comment: Ok, don't know, do I have to remove this as "the answer" to get it closed, as I think it is already / more directly answered in answer_id 1941499 about the concrete security risks?